# Uwp crash in modo release

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm creating an application in xamarin and I'm trying to export an executable in UWP release mode. I am having a big problem:

If the active check **.NET Native tool chain** the application crashes when it tries to start. Additionally, when I pass it through the "Windows App Certification Kit" to export it to the Microsoft store, I get these errors:

**Crashes and hangs: FAILED**

-Error Found: The crashes and hangs test detected the following errors:

- The executable C: \ Program Files \ WindowsApps \ xxxx.exe has been detected by the Windows error report and has been blocked.
- The application has been detected by the Windows error report and has been blocked.

Now, if I deactivate the **.NET Native tool chain** option, it runs perfectly but then I have another problem, passing it through the "Windows App Certification Kit" gives me this error:

**Supported APIs: FAILED**

-Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:

- The ExecuteAssembly API in uwphost.dll is not supported with this type of application.
- DllGetActivationFactory API in uwphost.dll is not supported for this type of application.

-Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps violates the Microsoft Store certification requirements.

What could I do to solve this?

Comment: Are you getting any error message or exception when the app crashes? You do need to compile with the .NET Native Toolchain in order to make a release build, so you need figure out and resolve the crash.

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT if I compile with that option the crash application when it starts .. if I remove that option if it runs perfectly, but the Windows App Certification Kit fails

Comment: I understand that. When an app crashes, there should be some error or exception thrown perhaps helping find WHY it crashes. So what is that error or exception?

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT The last mistake I am getting is this:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8F8AAA839 (KernelBase.dll) in MyClinicalApp.UWP.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80070002, 0x00000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000000000, 0x0000000000, 0x000000000000.

Comment: but if I'm not confused I can swear that this error came to me too.

runtimeblockedtypeinfo.cs no found @jgoldberger-MSFT

Comment: Is the app actually crashing or is it a build error such that the app fails to start? If you could provide a small sample that reproduces the issue, perhaps a stripped down version of the app with only startup code in it?

Comment: The application compiles perfectly, but when I give it to run about 5 sg from starting to crash with the error mentioned above. @jgoldberger-MSFT

Comment: Getting some form of test project that reproduces the crash would be very helpful. Without that, and/or better exception report with a human readable stack trace, it is very hard to tell what is causing the crash. If you need privacy, you can open a support case: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT Hello, I made an attempt to load in the microsoft store and they made a test that made the application crash, with the appcenter I could see where it crashed. You think that with this information you can help me. thanks.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59650405/uwp-xamarin-crash-in-submission-tests-when-i-try-to-upload-a-microsoft-store)