# What Dotnet native directives to use for AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM?

Tags: xamarin.forms, reflection, uwp

I'm using `AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM`'s `IAsyncCommand` and `AsyncCommand` in my `Xamarin.Forms` app. The UWP version of the app is compiled with .NET Native tool chain. When I do `SomeAsyncCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`, I get an exception:

`System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException: 'This operation cannot be carried out because metadata for the following object was removed for performance reasons:\n\n  EETypeRva:0x000976A0\n\nNo further information is available. Rebuild in debug mode for better information.\n\n'`

Note that this was a debug build. When I added a local copy of the library, I was able to find [the line that triggers the exception](https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices/blob/57444d0ecc32792cc2a3d06d57e97e4f059ac09f/src/AsyncAwaitBestPractices/WeakEventManager/EventManagerService.shared.cs#L180):

```
    static bool IsLightweightMethod(this MethodBase method)
    {
        var typeInfoRTDynamicMethod = typeof(DynamicMethod).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredNestedType("RTDynamicMethod");
        return ...
    }
```

The exception is triggered by `GetDeclaredNestedType("RTDynamicMethod")`. So the binaries do include the metadata of `DynamicMethod`, but not that of it's child type `RTDynamicMethod`. They have been removed because of .NET Native tool chain.

Now, I read that you can whitelist classes / namespaces / assemblies in project properties -> `Default.rd.xml`. But I can't seem to get the right element to whitelist the nested class. Here's what I tried:

```
<Assembly Name="System.Private.CoreLib" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Namespace Name="System.Reflection.Emit" Dynamic="Required All" />
<Type Name="System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod">
  <Type Name="RTDynamicMethod" Dynamic="Required All"/>
</Type>
```

Here `System.Private.CoreLib` is the assembly of DynamicMethod, `System.Reflection.Emit` is the namespace of `DynamicMethod` and `RTDynamicMethod`. As far as I understand, either of the three should work, yet none of them do. *Edit*: the type one gives me a warning: `Default.rd.xml(35): warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0027: Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod' could not be found.`

I also tried variations using `Type Name="System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod+RTDynamicMethod"`, using `<Library>`, with or without namespaces in type, etc.

Comment: I gave on this... Ended up using a work-around: clone `AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM`, add it to my solution and use the local copy, and cut out the reflection from `HandleEvent`. I wasn't using `DynamicMethod`s anywhere in my code, so I didn't need this part of `HandleEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can try to use the following code in the `Default.rd.xml`:

```
<Type Name="System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod" Dynamic="Required All">
<Type Name="System.Reflection.Emit.RTDynamicMethod" Dynamic="Required All">
```

For more information, you can check the [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59650405/uwp-xamarin-crash-in-submission-tests-when-i-try-to-upload-a-microsoft-store) and [the issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/978) on the github.

In addition, why did you add the tag .net 6.0? I have checked the package named `System.Reflection.Emit`, the last update time is 12/4/2019 and it does't support the .net 6.0.

Comment: Just tried this one, did not work either. You're right about the tag, I'll remove it. I did see the other question, and tried the `MissingMetaData` troubleshooter earlier, but I wasn't able to fix my problem with it.

Comment: You can try to report it to the github. @benk

Comment: Yes, I've created an issue on the `AsyncAwaitBestPractices` github